# A 2F1 Hypergeometric identity from a Feynman integral

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, special-functions, computer-algebra, hypergeometric-functions, feynman-integral

Using two different approaches to evaluating the dimensionally regularized ($d=4-2\epsilon$ dimensional Euclidean space), equal mass ($x=m^2$), 2-loop vacuum Feynman diagram
$$
\begin{align}
I(x) &= \int\frac{\mathrm{d}^dp}{\pi^{d/2}}\frac{\mathrm{d}^dk}{\pi^{d/2}}
      \frac1{(k^2+x)(p^2+x)((k+p)^2+x)} \\\
     &= \int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }\int _0^{\infty }
      \frac{e^{-x(s_1+s_2+s_3)}}{\left(s_1s_2+s_2s_3+s_3s_1\right)^{d/2}}
      \mathrm{d}s_1\mathrm{d}s_2\mathrm{d}s_3 \\\ 
     &= x^{d-3}\,\Gamma\left(2-\frac{d}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac{d}{2}\right)
        \,f(d)\,,
\end{align}
$$
the following hypergeometric identity arises
$$
\begin{align}
f(d) &=f_1(d) = 
2\, {}_2F_1\left(1,\frac{d-1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{3}\right)
-4^{2-d} 3^{(d - 3)/2} B\left(\frac{3 - d}2, \frac{3 - d}2\right) \\
&= f_2(d) = \frac{4}{3} \left(
{}_2F_1\left(1,\frac{d-1}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\frac{1 }{d-3}  {}_2F_1\left(1,\frac{d-1}{2};\frac{5-d}{2};-\frac{1}{3}\right) \right)\,,
\end{align}
$$
where the second term in $f_1(d)$ can be reduced with the identity 
$B(x,x)=2^{1-2x}B(x,1/2)$.

The identity $f_1(d)=f_2(d)$ checks out numerically and (provided no mistakes have been made in the calculations) it should be identically true. So far I have been unable to find a direct proof of the identity.

Can anyone here prove this identity or suggest a good approach?
A computer proof (using human checkable code/steps) is acceptable.

---

For convenience I've provided the Mathematica `InputForm` of the two functions:

```
f1[d_] := 2 Hypergeometric2F1[1, (d - 1)/2, 3/2, -1/3] - 
          2^(4 - 2 d) 3^((d - 3)/2) Beta[(3 - d)/2, (3 - d)/2]

f2[d_] := 4/3 (Hypergeometric2F1[1, (d - 1)/2, 3/2, -1/3] + 
          1/(d - 3) Hypergeometric2F1[1, (d - 1)/2, (5 - d)/2, -1/3])
```

---

**Aside:**
$f_1(d)$ comes from direct integration using Feynman parameters (my own calculation, I don't know of a reference that includes it).
$f_2(d)$ comes from direct integration using the Mellin-Barnes representation (the result presented above is a version of eqn(33) of [hep-ph/9304303](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9304303), see also references within) .

---

**Edit:**
I just noticed [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37787/proving-a-hypergeometric-function-identity/37836#37836) that mentions the [HolonomicFunctions](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/HolonomicFunctions/index.php) package for Mathematica. It shows that both functions obey the recursion
$(4+4 d)f_i(d+4)+(4-7 d)f_i(d+2)+(-6+3 d)f_i(d)=0$,
but of course, the integral diverges for integer $d\geq4$ and I need to prove the relation for all $d<4$ (dimensional reduction) or for all complex $d$ (dimensional regularization).

---

**Aside #2:**
Maybe I've been viewing this problem backwards, and I should not be using hypergeometric identities to check the Feynman integrals, but rather using the Feynman integrals as inspiration for new hypergeometric identities. See the new paper: 
[Finding new relationships between hypergeometric functions by evaluating Feynman integrals](http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.6019)

Comment: Standard methods for algorithmically verifying hypergeometric identities are described in Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger's A=B: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Comment: @Qiaochu It's been a long time since I flicked through A=B... I'll have to go back and look again.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using Mathematica, you definitely want to take a look at the extremely useful package [HolonomicFunctions](http://www.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/ergosum/RISC/HolonomicFunctions.html) by Christoph Koutschan.

In your particular example,

```
Annihilator[f1[d], {S[d]}]
```

shows that this function satisfies the recurrence
\begin{equation}
  (4+4d)f_1(d+4)+(4-7d)f_1(d+2)-(6-3d)f_1(d)=0.
\end{equation}

Once known, Mathematica itself can check symbolically that both of your functions satisfy this recurrence:

```
(4+4d)f1[d+4] + (4-7d)f1[d+2] - (6-3d)f1[d] // FullSimplify
(4+4d)f2[d+4] + (4-7d)f2[d+2] - (6-3d)f2[d] // FullSimplify
```

After checking initial conditions (which Mathematica can do) it follows that $f_1(d)=f_2(d)$ for all even integers $d$

But as I'm typing I see that the OP just figured all of this out by himself... ;)  So let me just mention that one strategy now could be to look at $f_1-f_2$, show that it satisfies the necessary exponential growth conditions (should be alright after combining the poles; apart from these each function seems to be good by itself), and apply [Carlson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson%27s_theorem). I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea of using Carlson's Theorem to show that $f_1-f_2$ is identically zero. It might be a little tricky though, since both $f_i(d)$ have poles at odd $d>2$. But I guess that knowing that $f_1(d)-f_2(d)=0$ for even integers is enough to use Carlson's theorem - so now I just need to check the growth conditions. 

Comment: @Armin: Ok, I haven't really done this kind of analysis before and am not sure how to get bounds on the expansion of $f_1-f_2$ around $d=\infty$... I tried using the integral form of the hypergeometric to extract some suitable asymptotics, but got nowhere. Would you mind expanding your answer on the use of Carlson's theorem?